# How can I get back the id of my object after save it on symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I was reading that if I make for example

```
$car = new Car();
$car->set('name','my car');
$car->set('color','orange');
and so on...
```

and if i make `$car->save();`

after that I will be able to make `$car->getCarId();` (in case the id field was mapped as CarId, Ive been trying this, but I get null everytime, and the info is persisted on the DB, I dont know how to retrieve that information, any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can we see your `schema.yml`? Which SGBD are you using? Does the field `car_id` is autoincremented?

Answer (score 1):

I depends on the ORM you are using:

For doctrine try:

$car->id; or $car->getId();

For propel only use:

$car->getId();

**Note**
These are only default values, if you defined something else then 'id' as your primary key field use the one you defined in the getter.